# How to install scrapy for python in visual code on windows?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I want to develop with python in visual code, how  How to install scrapy for python in visual code on windows?

```
import scrapy


class SafetyCaseItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    casetitle = scrapy.Field()
    casetype = scrapy.Field()
    posttime = scrapy.Field()
    caseurl = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    casecontent = scrapy.Field()
    ipage = scrapy.Field()
    nextlink = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: How is that code relevant?

Answer (score 0):

First open your command prompt;

Then goto your current directory;

```
cd path_of_your_folder
```

`cd` means choose directory.

Then run this command;

```
pip install scrapy
```

That is it. you are ready now.

**E.g,** If your project directory is my_project and is located inside the `Users/your_username_on_your_computer` directory, then in your command prompt, (you will be at `C:/Users/your_username_on_your_computer` location), type;

```
cd my_project
```

And press enter.

Now you are inside my_project directory where you want to use scrapy.

So now run this command inside your command prompt;

```
pip install scrapy
```

You are done now. Start writing some code.

Comment: For your kind information, a package doesnot depend on your code editor. So whether you are using VS code or any other code editor or IDE, this should work.

Comment: Also if you are using any virtual environment, don't forget to activate that first and then use my answer.